# DITA-OT with docker and bootstrap plugin ... how do i get access to the plugin directory?

Tags: docker, dita, dita-ot

I'm pretty new to Docker and also to Dita. I would like to run dita in a docker container - I installed and set up everything (under Windows) according to the instructions @

[Installing plug-ins in a Docker image](https://www.dita-ot.org/3.4/topics/creating-docker-images.html)

I also need the bootstrap plugin - so, my simple dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM docker.pkg.github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/dita-ot:3.4
RUN dita --install https://github.com/infotexture/dita-bootstrap/archive/3.3.zip
```

Then i built the image and created the container:

```
docker image build -t dita_test:1.0 .
docker container run -it -v /c/Admin/DITA:/src dita_test:1.0 -i /src/my.ditamap -o /src/out/dita-bootstrap -f html5-bootstrap -v
```

The output is generated without errors and everything looks good .... but, which I don't understood:

- how can I pass arguments to the bootstrap plugin? (e.g. --args.css site.css)
- how can I make the bootstrap directory available outside of the container ? (want to extend the bootstrap.hdf.xml file ...)

I found older documentation where the *opt/dita-ot/DITA-OT* directory was mounted. But it doesn't work or confuses me.

Help would be great ... thanks!
 -

Answer (score 0):

Might this version 3.4 documentation for [Running the dita command from a Docker image](https://www.dita-ot.org/3.4/topics/using-docker-images.html) help? (3.4 being the most current version of the DITA-OT at this time...)